# A number theoretical equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Are there integers $x$,$y$ and $z$, such that $x^2+y^2+z^2−4$ is divisible by $9$?

In other words, does there exist a solution to the following equation?

$x^2+y^2+z^2 \equiv 4\pmod9$

Comment: An easy triple is $(3, 3, 2)$ if you're just looking for some solution.

Comment: Please give your thoughts on the problem and what you tried or got stuck at.  This particular problem could have been solved via trial and error, or it could have been approached more analytically by looking at all of the square residues mod9, being namely $0,1,4,0,7,7,0,4,1$ and trying combinations of these to see if you could add up three of those to get $4,13$ or $22$.  (*that list of numbers comes simply from looking at $0^2,1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2,\dots$ each of which taken mod9*)

Answer (score 1):

$$x=2, y=0, z=0$$

is a solution